# Disabling checkbox from multiple conditions

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm developing a bus ticket booking ionic app and my app has a page where the user can select seating position(s) for his trip. My actual problem is disabling these seats (check boxes) from some conditions. These seats are loaded from the database.They are objects with 3 properties; "number", "status" and "check". The conditions are as follow:

> 1. If the "status" property is false, disable the seat automatically. This is executed as the page loads
> 2. Each time a seat is selected, it calls up a function which sets the check property to true and counts the number of selected check
>      boxes. If the number of selected boxes is equal to the defined "limit"
>      variable, all check boxes with a false "check" attribute are disabled.

The issue is that, these 2 conditions work perfectly when they are separate but when merged, they don't function anymore. Condition was obtained from this [fiddle project](http://jsfiddle.net/Quadraxas/9nsTd/4/)

The seats are generated from a function in the ts. The above conditions were applied only to the first generated row of seats for test purposes. The other rows only have the 1st condition applied to them

Here is the source code

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Loading, LoadingController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

import { BusProvider } from '../../providers/bus/bus';

import firebase from 'firebase';

@IonicPage({
  name: 'bus-plan'
})

@Component({
  selector: 'page-bus-plan',
  templateUrl: 'bus-plan.html',
})

export class BusPlanPage {

  seatList = [];

  busSeats = firebase.database().ref('/agency/bus/0/seats');

  public loading: Loading;

  person: any;

  public ticketdata = {
    departure: '',
    destination: '',
    date: '',
    hour: '',
    adult: 0,
    children: 0,
    class: '',
  }

  booked = false;

  backSeats = [65, 66, 67, 69, 70];

  public BusSize = {
    line1: [],
    line2: [],
    line3: [],
    line4: [],
  }

  limit = 3;

  checked = 0;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    console.log(this.limit)
    this.getBookingData();
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.busSeats.once('value', snapshot => {
      this.seatList = snapshot.val();
    }).then(seat => {
      if (seat)
        this.initArrays();
      else
        console.log("error")
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }

  checkLimit(a, b) {
    if (a && b)
      return true
    else
      return false
  }

  controlCbx(seat) {
    console.log(seat.check)
    seat.check = !seat.check

    if (seat.check)
      this.checked++
    else
      this.checked--
    console.log(this.checked)
  }

  initArrays() {
    var s1 = 15;
    var s2 = 31;
    var s3 = 47;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 16; i++) {
      this.BusSize.line1[i] = this.seatList[i - 1];
    }
    console.log(this.seatList)
    for (var j = 0; j <= 16; j++) {
      this.BusSize.line2[j] = this.seatList[j + 15];
    }
    for (var m = 0; m <= 16; m++) {
      this.BusSize.line3[m] = this.seatList[m + 31];
    }
    for (var k = 0; k <= 16; k++) {
      this.BusSize.line4[k] = this.seatList[k + 47];
    }
    this.BusSize.line1.shift();
    this.BusSize.line2.shift();
    this.BusSize.line3.shift();
    this.BusSize.line4.shift();
    this.BusSize.line4.map((obj) => {
      obj.check = false;
      return obj;
    });
    this.BusSize.line4.map((obj) => {
      obj.check = false;
      return obj;
    });
    this.BusSize.line3.map((obj) => {
      obj.check = false;
      return obj;
    });
    this.BusSize.line2.map((obj) => {
      obj.check = false;
      return obj;
    });
    this.BusSize.line1.map((obj) => {
      obj.check = false;
      return obj;
    });


    console.log(this.BusSize)
  }

  disableCbx() {
   let x = window.document.getElementById('checkbox');
   x.setAttribute
  }

  getArraysValue1(val) {
    return this.BusSize.line2[val].number;
  }

  getArraysValue2(val) {
    return this.BusSize.line3[val].number;
  }

  getArraysValue3(val) {
    return this.BusSize.line4[val].number;
  }

  getBookingData() {
    this.ticketdata.departure = this.navParams.get('departure');
    this.ticketdata.destination = this.navParams.get('destination');
    this.ticketdata.date = this.navParams.get('date');
    this.ticketdata.hour = this.navParams.get('hour');
    this.ticketdata.adult = this.navParams.get('adult');
    this.ticketdata.children = this.navParams.get('children');
    this.ticketdata.class = this.navParams.get('class');
    this.person = this.navParams.get('children') + this.navParams.get('adult');
    console.log(this.ticketdata)
  }

  goToConfirm(): void {
    this.navCtrl.push('confirmation', {
      'departure': this.ticketdata.departure,
      'destination': this.ticketdata.destination,
      'date': this.ticketdata.date,
      'hour': this.ticketdata.hour,
      'children': this.ticketdata.children,
      'adult': this.ticketdata.adult,
      'class': this.ticketdata.class,
    });
    console.log(this.ticketdata)
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

  }

  stringToBoolean(string) {
    switch (string.toLowerCase().trim()) {
      case "true": case "yes": case "1":
        return true;
      case "false": case "no": case "0":
        return false;
      default:
        return Boolean(string);
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<ion-header no-border>

    <ion-navbar hideBackButton=false color="transparent-20">

        <ion-title>

            <span class="title">Select your seats</span>

        </ion-title>

    </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

    <div id="key">

        <div id="available" class="keyseats"></div>

        <div>Available</div>

        <div id="selected" class="keyseats"></div>

        <div>Selected</div>

        <div id="booked" class="keyseats"></div>

        <div>Booked</div>

    </div>

    <div class="cabin">

        <ion-grid class="row">

            <!-- Row 1 from 1-16 -->
            <div style="position:relative; width:2.7em;" *ngFor="let seats of BusSize.line1; let i = index" id="row1">

                <ion-col class="seat">

                    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" (change)="controlCbx(seats)" value="{{seats.number}}" id="{{seats.number}}"  [disabled]="(seats.status=='false' checked==limit && !BusSize.line1[i].check) ? true : false "
                    />

                    <label class="seatlabel" for="{{seats.number}}">{{seats.number}}</label>

                </ion-col>

            </div>

            <!-- Row 2 from 17-32 -->
            <div style="position:absolute; margin-left: 1em;">
                <div style="position:relative; width:2.7em; margin-left: 3em;" *ngFor="let seats of BusSize.line2" id="row2">

                    <ion-col class="seat">

                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{seats.number}}" id="{{seats.number}}" ng-model="num" [disabled]="!stringToBoolean(seats.status)"
                        />

                        <label class="seatlabel" for="{{seats.number}}">{{seats.number}}</label>

                    </ion-col>

                </div>

            </div>


            <!-- Row 3 from 33-48 -->
            <div style="position:absolute; right: 0; margin-right: 5.7em;">
                <div style="position:relative; width:2.7em;" *ngFor="let seats of BusSize.line3" id="row3">

                    <ion-col class="seat">

                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{seats.number}}" id="{{seats.number}}" ng-model="num" [disabled]="!stringToBoolean(seats.status)"
                        />

                        <label class="seatlabel" for="{{seats.number}}">{{seats.number}}</label>

                    </ion-col>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Row 4 from 49-64 -->
            <div style="position:absolute; right: 0; margin-right: 1.6em;">
                <div style="position:relative; width:2.7em;" *ngFor="let seats of BusSize.line4" id="row4">

                    <ion-col class="seat">

                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{seats.number}}" id="{{seats.number}}" ng-model="num" [disabled]="!stringToBoolean(seats.status)"
                        />

                        <label class="seatlabel" for="{{seats.number}}">{{seats.number}}</label>

                    </ion-col>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Row 5 from 65-69 -->
            <ion-row id="row5" class="seats">

                <ion-col *ngFor="let seats of backSeats;" class="seat seat2">

                    <input (change)='test()' type="checkbox" value="{{seats}}" id="{{seats}}" />

                    <label for="{{seats}}">{{seats}}</label>

                </ion-col>

            </ion-row>

        </ion-grid>

    </div>

    <button ion-button block (click)='goToConfirm()' icon-right color="light">
    CONFIRM <ion-icon ios="ios-checkmark" md="md-checkmark"></ion-icon>
    </button>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think issue is with the disabled check condition added for the checkbox. As a suggestion for better maintainability of the code you can create function like canSelectSeats() and use it in the disabled property instead of adding logic inline in html. And the function would return a boolean by checking the condition like below.

In .ts file of the page

```
canSelectSeats(seats, index):boolean {
 return this.checked < limit && seats.status=='false' && !BusSize.line1[index].check;
}
```

In html page

```
[disabled]="canSelectSeats(seats, i)"
```

*I am not sure about the last line1[index] check condition is for so you can change as you desire.